# How to launch an application using rdp(remote desktop protocol) in windows 10?

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp, launching-application

I am trying to launch notepad through rdp in remote machine. I tried editing rdp file with this code

```
alternate shell:s:"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

But didn't worked.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
alternate shell:s:"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
shell working directory:s:"C:\Windows\System32\"
```